# Can I use Capacitor Plugins with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I have an app based on Ionic V1 and Cordova. I know that some Cordova plugins can be used with Capacitor, but can it be used the other way around? Can I use Capacitor plugins with Cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t. Cordova plugins work in Capacitor because Capacitor includes compatibility code.
Since Cordova was created before Capacitor existed, there is no compatibility code yet.